# Software/Websites for testing packet losses/sustained uploading

Tags: networking, router

Currently, my internet has gotten to the point where I get ~25-35% packet losses from the previous ~3-6% loss. This only occurs when I have my wireless internet turned on in the modem, because there are no packet losses when I disable it. This also doesn't occur 24/7, implying that this is caused by somebody in the house using the wireless connection. I'm using Shaw Communications for my internet provider and their Motorola SBG6782 modem.

As a side note, there are 2 wireless frequencies that the modem can use at the same time, which is the normal one and a 5G connection. When I turn off the wireless, I only turn off the normal one, as nobody in the house has access to the 5G connection besides me.

I plan on putting up a question to Shaw, but before that I want to get more data behind this situation.

I've run 5 tests using WinMTR. The first 2 involved using the Ethernet connection with wireless turned on while the last 3 involved Ethernet connection with wireless turned off and browsing the internet with HD youtube videos in the background playing. All trace routes were done to google.ca

Test 2: [Ethernet, wireless on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl7Ss.png)

Test 5: [Ethernet, wireless off, HD youtube videos playing in the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctot6.png)

The two causes that I think may be causing this problem is either something wrong with the modem and its wireless technology, or a case of buffer bloating. I'm not sure if I can reliably test for the case of buffer bloating, so I will need software/websites that can test uploading at the maximum speed that my internet plan can allow. Speedtests won't work, as I need something that I can use to actually upload a lot of data. If it's not one of these two issues, then hopefully I can get help in finding out the real cause.

Comment: 3-6% is extremely high why was it so high?

Comment: The fact that you get packet loss to your router means it's either the router or the wireless that is the problem.